# Layouts and modules

Tags: magento-1.8, product, up-sells

i'm trying to use upsell template of magento to display a list of products that have same specific attribute, as @Amit Bera suggested in this question [Using upsells products template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98868/using-upsells-products-template/98875?noredirect=1#comment133297_98875).
I created a custom module with namespace Mymodule and name "Samecollection" so the structure is `/magento/app/code/local/Mymodule/Samecollection/Block/Product/List`. Inside it i created a block class Customcollection that inherits *`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell`* as follow :

```
class Mymodule_Samecollection_Block_Product_List_Customcollection extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell {
        protected function _prepareData() {
                $_product = Mage::registry('product');
                $this->_itemCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('author',array('like'=>$product->getAuthor()));

                $this->_itemCollection->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection)
                ->addStoreFilter();
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
                $this->_itemCollection->load();

  }

}
```

I declared the block in `/etc/config.xml` of `Mymodule_SameCollection` as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <config>
      <modules>
          <Mymodule_Samecollection>
              <version>1.0.0</version>
          </Mymodule_Samecollection>
      </modules>
      <global>
          <!-- start of block -->
          <blocks>
              <samecollection>
                  <class>Mymodule_Samecollection_Block</class>
              </samecollection>
          </blocks>
      </global>
  </config>
```

I then added my block to the layout inside `<catalog_product_view></catalog_product_view>`:

```
<block type="samecollection/product_list_customcollection" name="same_collection"  template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
        </block>
```

Finally in my product view, i called the layout :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('same_collection');?>
```

I have checked if my module was activated and it is.
I tried adding another block class similar to upsell class to the `mage/core/catalog/bloc/product/list` (*not recommended, i'm aware of that*) in an test environment with another template just to debug and check if my collection is populated and the child is rendered with method `getChildHtml()` and it was rendered.
I want to use this module approach but i don't know but i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code has an error

In your `Mymodule_Samecollection_Block_Product_List_Customcollection` class, change this line

```
$this->_itemCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getaddAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('author',array('like'=>$product->getAuthor()));
```

for this one

```
$this->_itemCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('author',array('like'=>$product->getAuthor()));
```

Notice the change: `getaddAttributeToSelect()` does not exist (in a default installation, at least)

Besides that, maybe you want to add '%' in your `LIKE` query to get better results. But this depends by the `author` attribute definition

**UPDATE**

In addition to this, you are getting the product from the registry & assigning it to `$_product` variable, but in your query you are using `$product->getAuthor()`, without the underscore. Again, a typo error

Comment: It was just a typo ! the problem is that nothing is displayed; like if the block is not called inside view.phtml of product.
I tested the collection, it renders products correclty when called directly from view.phtml

Comment: In addition to this, you are getting the product from the registry & assigning it to $_product variable, but in your query you are using $product->getAuthor(), without the underscore. Again, a typo error

Comment: I corrected all the possible typos, i even created a hello world template in the same location as upsell.phtml and i tried to render the layout using that block to no avail. `<block type="samecollection/product_list_customcollection" name="same_collection" template="catalog/product/list/helloworld.phtml"></block>`