# How should I call upsell.phtml file in sales/order/items.phtml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, sales-order, up-sells

I want You may also like section on order at the end.
The content on order page comes from `sales/order/items.phtml` file.
I want to call the "you may also like" section in this file, the You may also like section comes from `product/list/upsell.phtml` file. Now I want to call this section in `sales/order/items.phtml` file
I also tried to make changes in xml file. How can I get this?

```
<sales_order_view translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Order View</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_info" as="info" name="sales.order.info">
            <block type="sales/order_info_buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" />
        </block>
        <block type="sales/order_view" name="sales.order.view">
            <block type="sales/order_items" name="order_items" template="sales/order/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                    <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="4" class="a-right"</value></action>
                    <action method="setValueProperties"><value>class="last a-right"</value></action>
                    <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml" />
                </block>
                <block type="product/list_upsell" name="upsell_products" template="product/list/upsell.phtml" />
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="sales.order.info">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>view</name><path></path><label>Order Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path>*/*/invoice</path><label>Invoices</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path>*/*/shipment</path><label>Shipments</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>creditmemo</name><path>*/*/creditmemo</path><label>Refunds</label></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" translate="label">
        <label>Additional Product Info</label>
    </block>
</sales_order_view>
```

Comment: Your need is to display the `upsells` block in `sales/order/items.phtml` ?

Comment: @Prince Yes..exactly..!

Comment: @Prince, How can I achieve this, Any solution?

Comment: Look my answer please

Answer (score 1):

**Up-sells** for a product are items that you would like your customer to buy instead of the product that he is viewing, natively this block is displayed in `catalog/product/view.phtml`

Now you want to display this upsells block in `sales/order/items.phtml` you have to do this:

1)  `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` add this code :

```
<sales_order_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
            <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>6</limit></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</sales_order_view>
```

2) `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/sales/order/items.phtml` add this code where you want to display this new upsells block :

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('product.info.upsell') ?>
```

**EDIT:**

As I explained at the beginning of my answer the **upsells** are related to minimum one product! and the upsells block have `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell` class and he can't get a principal product where you are trying to display it in `sales/order/view` because you haven't any product !

So the first part of layout that i gave you is correct, now the second part you have to customise `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell` please follow this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98875/48355)

**EDIT 2 :**

You have to customise it according your need, please replace the `_prepareData()` of the rewrited one with the code bellow

```
protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $myProductId = 704; // here you put the product id that you have related the upsells on it
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($myProductId);
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getUpSellProductCollection()
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;
        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );

            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
//        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);

        if ($this->getItemLimit('upsell') > 0) {
            $this->_itemCollection->setPageSize($this->getItemLimit('upsell'));
        }

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        /**
         * Updating collection with desired items
         */
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_upsell', array(
            'product'       => $product,
            'collection'    => $this->_itemCollection,
            'limit'         => $this->getItemLimit()
        ));

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Error occured..:(
*Call to a member function getUpSellProductCollection() on null*

Comment: yes it's logic because you haven't any product related to the upsells, look my edit please

Comment: Still not getting :(

Comment: Look my update please.

Comment: ,And what to change in item.phtml and local.xml?

Comment: in local : `<block type="the/new_one"`